# Calling another file from the file ajax is trying to post data to

Tags: ajax

Can a function in another file be called from the file ajax is trying to post data to ?

Comment: Possibly, but you haven't given us much to work with here.  What language?  What sort of file is the Ajax call posting to?

Comment: Im sorry its php. Im in index.php which has the ajax function and this function posts data to data.php. But there are functions inside data.php which communicate with the DB.                                                    index.php -> data.php -> insertintodb.php

Comment: You can use `include` or `require` in data.php just as you would in any other PHP file...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you aren't able to use a Javascript callback, you could use post variables to fire a function in file 2.

File 1 code would send a post variable called "call_function" with either a true or false value.

File 2 code:

```
<?php 
if($_POST['call_function'] == 'true')
{
    file2function();
}

function file2function()
{
     // do your stuff after loaded into file 1
}
?>
```

You could try eval():

File 1 code:

```
$.ajax({ url: "two.php", type: "POST", data: data, cache: false, success: function (html) { alert(html); } });
```

File 2 code:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['success'])) eval($_POST['success']);
// should run the function in your variable

?>
```

Source - http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_misc_eval.asp

Comment: user597441 is looking to call server-side functions, not client-side ones.

Comment: exactly .. its a server side function

Comment: I changed it to allow post variables to fire a php function... Instead of using JS function.

Comment: one.php-- has input fields and this function                       $.ajax({
   url: "two.php",
   type: "POST",
   data: data,
   cache: false,
   success: function (html) {
    alert(html);
   }
  });                                                            the data is taken to two.php which has function to write to DB in three.php                                                                  but i cannot write the functions is three.php to two.php

Comment: Are you getting an error when you `include "three.php";` or call some function in the file?

Comment: im also writing huge amounts of data into DB and so it takes time for which i thought ajax would be a solution.

Comment: So do you not have access to the other PHP files?

Comment: no i dont get any error.. but ajax wont go to the success function. But if I dont call a function from three.php in success: it works

Comment: I guess I am trying to figure out why you are trying to put a function into a post variable. Is there a reason you are doing that and not building a function on the php file that is being loaded?

Comment: well i cannot put functions of one class into another because it would not be proper method in my case

Comment: It's possible the Ajax call times out before the DB operations are completed, which would explain why the onSuccess callback is never getting fired.